# Where can our customers manage their licenses?

Tags: appexchange, management

We are building an app that will be sold in the AppExchange. Where can customers that purchase our app manage the licenses they buy for their users? For example - say Acme Co. buys 10 seats for 10 of their users. Where do they allocate those seats to individual users? Is that done in the AppExchange, our app, or both?

Where are seats added and removed? Is that also just in the AppExchange or can that be done within our app as well?

Appreciate the help everyone!

Answer (score 3):

For a subscriber, the licenses are added at the user level (Setup > Manage Users > Users). There's a related list that allows administrators to add/remove licenses. Subscribers can view the licenses available in Setup > Company Profile > Company Information.

Subscribers must contact you or use a service you provide to increase license count. Since that typically involves additional contracts, most ISVs prefer to do this manually instead of automatically.

As an ISV, you can add/remove licenses from a subscriber at any time after installing the [LMA](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/), including the number of seats, expiration date, and if the license is per-user or per-org (a "site-wide" license), as well as if this is a trial mode or not.

The AppExchange only manages customer ratings, listings, etc. The licenses are stored in an org of your choosing (typically your production org or an ISV developer org).

Comment: Thanks for the information. In particular though, we're wondering how our managed App will be able to *check* to make sure a particular user has a license in our subscriber's organization before allowing any paid functionality. It sounds like if the subscriber information is stored in the LMA app in our production Org then our deployed App will need to check against that source somehow, is that correct? Is there some custom Apex code or API calls we'll need to do in order to accomplish this? Or how else is this typically done?

Comment: @Emil In most cases, the system itself will block access to objects, fields, pages, and classes in your package without a license assigned. If you need to determine if a user is licensed, perhaps within a trigger or a global class, use UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed.

Comment: thanks! Are there test licenses we can test with?

Comment: @Emil you can install it in any org you want. Salesforce only charges you for licenses you're charging. You're free to use free licenses to demo your app or for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You will Install an app called LMA from appexchange in your salesforce Instance where you want to manage your leads and track the installs and license

The process for LMA is as below

1.As soon as someone installs your app as Trial you get them in your org as Lead and a License is associated

2.As soon as you convert them to Account and Contact its linked to license .

[image]